# iPhone how to check if the phone can send/receive mail using native mail app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

I have an enterprise mobile device management system that enables the phone to connect to the enterprise network and send/receive enterprise mail. This service is rather unstable, and I'd like to know how it's stability can be tested, to see when the phone can and cannot send/receive mail.

Something tells me that this kind of activity would be impossible on a non-jailbroken iPhone, and most likely the MDM service provider would have to provide tools to check service integrity.

**Can anyone confirm that there's no way to check if the native mail app can send/receive mail with the current configuration?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to do something like this:

```
   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
       //App can send mail
   }
```

Comment: The canSendMail returns true in a simulator - Should it?